# Java pattern to enforce methods are ran

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am racking my brain for a solution. I am sure its something small I am overlooking.
I want a way to enforce a method is filled out and ran.
So for example, I want a migration class

```
public interface IMigration
{
   boolean preConditionCheck();

   boolean runMigration();

   boolean postCondition();
}
```

I want the method preConditionCheck and postCondition to run after the run migration step.

With the interface you have to fill it out but nothing says it has to be ran.

Is there a pattern to enforce a order on this?

Comment: Can you give a bit more context: what code is supposed to *execute* the `IMigration` implementations? Usually for this kind of interface, you'll have multiple implementations and only one consumer. So "enforcement" would simply mean that the consumer is properly implemented. Do you have multiple consumers of this interface?

Comment: By the way, you might find [*Jakarta Bean Validation*](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/bean-validation/) handy for validating an object’s proper state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your scenario, you can use the [Template Method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

> Template method defines the steps to execute an algorithm
> and it can provide a default implementation that might be common for
> all or some of the subclasses

**An Example below**

```
public abstract class BaseClass {
    public final void doWork() {
        preConditionCheck();
        runMigration();
        postCondition();
    }

    protected abstract void preConditionCheck();
    protected abstract void runMigration();
    protected abstract void postCondition();
}
```

> Usage:

```
public class MyClass extends BaseClass {
    protected void preConditionCheck() {
        // Set up resources or perform any necessary pre-processing
    }
    protected void runMigration() {
        // Perform the actual work here
    }
    protected void postCondition() {
        // Clean up resources or perform any necessary post-processing
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on how strict you need/want to be, you should consider making `doWork()` final, so that subclasses can't alter the sequence of methods being called.

Comment: @E-Riz Good catch. Updated the code to reflect the same